# Samba share automatically do username and password

Tags: samba, cifs

Right now I'm connecting to network shares on my windows 7 machine with a command like `sudo mount -o username=Robert //192.168.1.56/share /mnt/share` and then it asks for my password. No big deal, but I'd rather have it just connect properly when I do `sudo mount //192.168.1.56/share /mnt/share`.

I know there's a config file to do this somewhere, I'm just not sure what/where it is and how it should be set up. I'd rather not do `-o username=Robert,password=hunter123`.

Samba is whatever is the latest and greatest from debain testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting your username and password in /etc/fstab. Of course, there are some security implications in doing so, as all users on your system will be able to see the password.

E.g. add a line like::

//192.168.1.56/share /mnt/share cifs username=robert,password=hunter123 0 0

See also `man mount.cifs`, which documents some of the alternative ways in which you could pass credentials.

Comment: credentials file sounds good, it's a bit better anyway. I'll try a few things out.

Comment: Ended up just making a new `alias mountc='sudo mount -o credentials=/home/robert/.smbcred'` and that worked fine. Could've made it an alias with username=USER,password=PASSWORD, but I can chmod my credentials file since it's read by root.

Answer (score 1):

you could also set up the smb.conf file (/etc/samba/smb.conf) to add the share sans-authentication.

```
# /etc/samba/smb.conf file for COMPLETELY INSECURE SHARING
# You need to replace each "USER_NAME" instance with your username
# Apps... Accessories... gedit Text Editor. Search... Replace

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = [HOSTNAME OF YOUR SERVER]
security = share
name resolve order = hosts lmhosts

[SHARE NAME]
path = /path/to/share
force user = [username on server]
force group = [group on server]
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

restart samba with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart
```

and the share should show uo as normal, and will not require authentication.

note everyone on the network will be able to see and access this share.

Comment: The share is open to read only for everyone, I need to log in to do file moves and deletions, so that's not an issue. I'd still need to authenticate with the windows machine with this.